# action by key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeypress

I'm designing a web based accounting software. I would like to open the "new accounting document" whenever the user press <kbd>N</kbd> key for example. And open "settings" whenever he/she is pressing <kbd>S</kbd> key.

I saw some scripts based on JavaScript and jQuery. But they did not work exactly. Can anyone help me please ?

I have tried this script:

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code. It will help in answering.

Comment: "Whenever the user press N key" - I'm not sure what "accounting document" means to you, but I would expect some fields for the user to enter account names and other non-numeric information, so what happens when they want to put an "N" or "S" in their account names?

Comment: Just saw your update with code - what's the problem with it? It says right there in the comment that it is trying to trap the Enter key. Have a look at [this table of key codes.](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which==78) {
      // "n"
    }
    if(e.which==83) {
      // "s"
    }
});
```

To prevent if an input is focused:

```
$("body").on("focus",":input", function(){ $(document).unbind('keyup'); });
$("body").on("blur",":input", function(){ $(document).bind('keyup', function(e){ etc.... });
```

You might want to put the `bind` function into its own function so you don't duplicate code. e.g:

```
function bindKeyup(){
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
      if(e.which==78) {
        // "n"
      }
      if(e.which==83) {
        // "s"
      }
    });
}
$("body").on("focus",":input", function(){ $(document).unbind('keyup'); });
$("body").on("blur",":input", function(){ bindKeyup(); });
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas. But how can I prevent this function if user's cursor is focused on a text box?

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your answers.
Accidentally I found something similar to your answers. It works good too.
Take a look at it: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Comment: can you fiddle this?

Answer (score 3):

You can detech keypresses in jQuery using either [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) or [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) methods, here is a quick example :

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) { // the event variable contains the key pressed
 if(event.which == 78) { // N keycode
   //Do something
 }
});
```

Here is a list of keycodes : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

### Update 1

.keyup and .keydown have different affects - as per comments from @ThomasClayson -: keyup is the best one to go for as keypress will repeat if the key is held down. it registers an event for each character inserted. It also doesn't register modifier keys such as shift (although not necessary here, it might be something to keep in mind)

### Update 2

This is from the jQuery keyup doc site :

> To determine which key was pressed, examine the event object that is
>   passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing
>   properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which
>   property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the key code. This
>   code corresponds to a key on the keyboard, including codes for special
>   keys such as arrows.

Affectively meaning that `which.event` is all you need to determine which key has been used. Thanks @nnnnnn

Comment: `keyup` is the best one to go for as `keypress` will repeat if the key is held down. it registers an event for each character inserted. It also doesn't register modifier keys such as shift (although not necessary here, it might be something to keep in mind).

Comment: @ThomasClayson thanks - updated my answer accordingly ... always learning me ....

Comment: If you are using jQuery you should be safe to assume that `event.which` will be there - jQuery normalises it for you.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks - i didnt even ask the question and ive learnt 2 things here ... thank you .... :-)

Comment: @ManseUK there is more to jquery than meets the eye

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on the `.keyCode()` attribute of the event object. You can interrogate that to discover which key was pressed and act accordingly. I'd also suggest you add modifier keys to your shortcuts, such as <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, so that when someone is innocently typing in an input, the panel doesn't pop up. In the example below I've used <kbd>Shift</kbd>

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        switch(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) {
            case 78: // N pressed
                myNPressedHandler();
                break;
            case 83: // S pressed
                mySPressedHandler();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: again, criticising... lol, i'm so sorry! Keypress is a bad event to check for, it fires recurringly if a user holds down the key in question. The best one to check for is `keyup` as this is the definitive "I've pressed a key and finished pressing it". Also keypress doesn't register shift and alt keys as you've suggested. http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: @Thomas lol - it's early on a monday morning for me and my hands are working quicker than my fingers.

Comment: Its ok. :) Your answers are very good, and I don't mean to sound like a smart ass at all! Just passing on the mistakes and knowledge I've made and accumulated as a result. :p

Comment: Thank you, and as an example of my stupidity this morning I wrote "hands typing quicker than my fingers", I meant "quicker than my brain". With that, I'm off for a while lol :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var keycode= (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
       if(keyCode==78) {
      // "n"
    }else if(keyCode==83) {
      // "s"
    }

});
```