# Fire javascript when a specific key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to work on a, you can say a practice project,
In which an audio file will be played in background,
Which would be be Paused if SPACEBAR key is pressed and
Play when it's pressed again.
so, is there anything like onkeypress, keydown etc which can be added to body of html.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [action by key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294876/action-by-key-press)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execute code after press on spacebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386354/execute-code-after-press-on-spacebar)

Comment: Nikola Lukic  , well thers's nothing like textbox i mentioned.

Comment: Ivar and Dineth Cooray ,well the links are for my purpose ...thnx

Comment: Thanks , to.....whoever gifted me -1 ...lol

Answer (score 0):

```
var isplaying = false;
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      if (isplaying) {
        //Code for pause
      } else {
        //Code for play
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable to store current state and modify that on key press event as

```
var state=0; // 0 for play, 1 for pause
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 32){
    if(state==0)
       {
        state=1;
        //Run your code to pause
        }
     else{
        state=0;
        //Run your code to play
      }
}
}
```