# Implementing keyboard event listener for my rock-paper-scissors JavaScript game

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement keyboard event listeners to this rock-paper-scissors game. I was only able to make it work for "rock" when I press any key. But I would like to associate the "w" key for Rock, the "e" for paper and "r" for scissors, or something like that. Can anybody give my a clue on how to do it?

```
     const main = () => {

         rockDiv.addEventListener('click', () => game("rock"))

         paperDiv.addEventListener('click', () => game("paper"))

         scissorsDiv.addEventListener('click', () => game("scissors"))

         // implementing key event listener to play by keyboard: 

         document.body.addEventListener('keyup', () => game("rock"))
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keydown + keyup events for specific keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345870/keydown-keyup-events-for-specific-keys)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [action by key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294876/action-by-key-press)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are forgetting to listen to which key is pressed so the following code can make it work

```
const main = () => {

         rockDiv.addEventListener('click', () => game("rock"))

         paperDiv.addEventListener('click', () => game("paper"))

         scissorsDiv.addEventListener('click', () => game("scissors"))

         // implementing key event listener to play by keyboard: 

         document.body.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
         //if key is w
         if (event.keyCode === 87) 
            game("rock")
         //if key is e
         if (event.keyCode === 69) 
            game("paper")
         //if key is r
         if (event.keyCode === 82) 
            game("scissors")


        )
    }
```

more about keys and their codes https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Answer (score 0):

you are good, you just need the event key so you can use it.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const {
    key,
    keyCode
  } = event;
  document.getElementById('keys').innerHTML = `${key} (${keyCode})`

  // if you want to listen for R, P, S.
  switch (keyCode) {
    case 82:
      console.log('Rock');
      break;
    case 80:
      console.log('Paper');
      break;
    case 83:
      console.log('scissors');
      break;
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
  last key pressed:
  <p id="keys"> nothing </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)